# “The ConnectionString property has not been initialized” error

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, database-connection, connection-string

I am new at c# and I research some project on internet. I found a project but when I start the project I get

> "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

How can I fix it? Here is the code:

```
 public Database(string dbType, string str, string adapter = null)
    {
        if (adapter != null)
        {
            Adapter(adapter);
        }

        _DbType = dbType;
        var provider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(Adapter());
        _Conn = provider.CreateConnection();
        _Conn.ConnectionString = str;
        _Conn.Open();
    }
```

Comment: Show us full code. Where is `_Conn` defined?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. An SqlConnection object needs a connectionstring before trying to open the connection. So when you build the connection you pass the connectionstring or set the ConnectionString property before opening.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395222/c-sharp-database-the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized). (hope it can help you)