# 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.' TO FIX

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently getting the error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'
I would like some help to fix this as I am trying to input data from a c#form (multiple textboxes) to an SQL data base form my current code is

```
 private void AcceptData()
    {
        using (Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("INPUT INTO Person", Connection))//, Connection
        {
            DataTable RegisterTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(RegisterTable); //System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.' TO FIX

            string name = textBox1.Text;
            string organisation = textBox3.Text;
            DateTime Time = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            string strDateTimeIn = Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff");
            string query = "INSERT INTO Person (Name,Organisation,TimeIn) VALUES('" + name + "','" + organisation + "','" +strDateTimeIn+ "')";
            SqlCommand SignIn = new SqlCommand(query,Connection);
            SignIn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you

The connection string used is :`string connectionString = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Register.mdf;Integrated Security=True");`

Comment: @Corak Probably because it's LocalDB (e.g. [like this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/localdb-automatic-instance-with-specific-data-file/))

Comment: @DavidG - ah, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open the connection

```
using (Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("INPUT INTO Person", Connection))//, Connection
        {
            DataTable RegisterTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(RegisterTable); //System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.' TO FIX

            string name = textBox1.Text;
            string organisation = textBox3.Text;
            DateTime Time = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            string strDateTimeIn = Time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff");
            string query = "INSERT INTO Person (Name,Organisation,TimeIn) VALUES('" + name + "','" + organisation + "','" +strDateTimeIn+ "')";
            SqlCommand SignIn = new SqlCommand(query,Connection);
            SignIn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"* clearly indicates that the connection string property for opening a `SqlConnection` has not assigned properly inside the method. To fix this issue, either assign the connection string in method body like this:

```
private void AcceptData()
{
    // assumed the connection string obtained from app.config or web.config file
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        Connection.Open(); // open the connection before using adapter
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("INPUT INTO Person", Connection))
        {
            // other stuff
        }
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

Or pass the connection string as method argument:

```
private void AcceptData(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        Connection.Open(); // open the connection before using adapter
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("INPUT INTO Person", Connection))
        {
            // other stuff
        }
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

References:

[How to fix "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007786/how-to-fix-the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized)

[C# Database The ConnectionString property has not been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395222/c-sharp-database-the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized)